# Frechet derivative of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory

Let an operator $T:C[a,b]\to C[a,b]$ be defined as:

\begin{equation}
(Tu)(x)=\int_{a}^{b}K(x,t)f(t,u(t))dt
\end{equation}
where $K:[a,b]\times[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f:[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are given functions. 
How can I compute the Frechet derivative of $T$?

Comment: The standard way. Take a variation $v$, form the increment $T(u+\varepsilon v)$ take the derivative $\left.\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\epsilon=0}T(u+\varepsilon v)$. Switch derivative and integral and so on.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Maybe I have not made the question clear. I know in theory what I should do, the thing is how do I apply it. At what am I reading atm this is a trivial example but only the result is given. What about the method, the steps between? Thank you and sorry for not making it clear before.

Comment: have you thought of integral of K(x,t).(f_u).u' dt?

Comment: @Adelafif yes I know that the answer is this, but I need the steps between. The method of how to end up with $T'(u)(h)=\int_{a}^{b}K(x,t)f_u(t,u)h(t)dt$..

Comment: Anyone who could assist me with this one? I do know that it is trivial, just for once so I can follow the method for other examples too...

Comment: Have you ever studied Lagrangian or Hamiltonian mechanics? There is a principle called "the stationary action principle", in which you have an integral (the "action") $$S(q)=\int_{a_0}^{a_1}L(\dot q(t), q(t))\, dt$$ and the principle tells you that the equation of motion is $$dS(u)=0.$$

Comment: ...How do you compute $dS(u)$? You take an "admissible variation" $\delta q$ and you compute $$\begin{split} \left.\frac d{d\epsilon}S(q+\epsilon \delta q)\right|_{\epsilon=0} &= \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\left.\frac\partial{\partial \epsilon}L(\dot q+\epsilon\dot{\delta q}, q+\epsilon\delta q)\right|_{\epsilon =0}\, dt \\ &=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\dot{\delta q } + \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\delta q\, dt\end{split}$$And so on. This is the way you find Euler-Lagrange's equations of motion.

Comment: ... In the problem at hand you have to do *exactly* the same computation, the only difference being that your independent variable is now called $u$ instead of $q$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you and sorry for all the trouble!

Answer (score 1):

**Differentiation under integral sign.** Assume:

1. $[a, b]$ is a compact interval of $\Bbb R$;
2. $\mathrm{E}_1, \mathrm{E}_2$ are normed and complete (completeness is *essential* as Riemann integral fails to exist for non-complete vector spaces) linear spaces;
3. $\mathrm{O}$ is an open set in $\mathrm{E}_1$;
4. $f:[a, b] \times \mathrm{O} \to \mathrm{E}_2$ is a continuous and
   $\mathbf{D}_2f$ exists and is continuous.

Then, the function $\displaystyle \varphi(x) = \int\limits_a^b dt\ f(t, x)$ defines a continuous (resp. differentiable with continuity) function $\mathrm{O} \to \mathrm{E}_2$ and its derivative is given by $\displaystyle \mathbf{D} \varphi(x) = \int\limits_a^b dt\ \mathbf{D}_2 f(t, x).$

**To your exercise.** Define $\varphi:[a,b] \times \mathscr{C}[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ by $\varphi(t, u) = u(t),$ which is a continuous bilinear map, so $\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial u} \cdot h = h(t).$ The function $f$ has to be assumed continuous with a continous partial derivative with respect to the second factor (or if $f$ is a continous function of $(t, y),$ then you want $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ to be continuous also). By chain rule, if $\psi(t, u) = f(t, u(t)) = f(t, \varphi(t, u)),$ then $\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial u} \cdot h = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial u} \cdot h = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} h(t).$ Therefore, $$\mathbf{D}\mathrm{T}(u) \cdot h = \int\limits_a^b dt\ \mathrm{K}(\ , t) \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} h(t) \in \mathscr{C}[a,b]$$
is the continuous function
$$x \mapsto \int\limits_a^b dt\ \mathrm{K}(x, t) \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} h(t).$$